# Double refund on a purchase

Tags: halacha, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, gezel-stealing

Take the following hypothetical scenario: I bought an item from a third-party retailer. The item was faulty, so I reached out to the manufacturer for a refund. The manufacturer didn't respond, so I went back to the retailer and returned the item. After that, the manufacturer got back to me and offered a refund.

Do I get to keep both refunds, or must I return one of them? (Let's assume both parties are Jewish.)

How about the following, similar case: I bought an item, but the manufacturer sent me the wrong one. They refunded the money, but allowed me to keep the item. May I sell the item and keep the profits?

Comment: If the seller is Gentile, offhand, sounds like you can rely on *Ta'ut Nachri*, which would let you keep the 2nd refund. *Minhag chassidut*, of course, would be to return the item. For Jews, perhaps, there is a concept of *ye'ush*?

Comment: How is your question / scenario different from the answers in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8266/5275? If it's the same, then this question is a dupe.

Comment: @DanF That's... interesting. You're implying that providing a refund is intrinsically an act of yi'ush.

Comment: @DanF In the linked question the money is entirely the mistake of the seller providing too much change. Here each individual party is acting correctly, but the "mistake" happened as a result of the time delay between the the first and second parties, each of which is an independent actor.

Comment: Does Halakha recognize your rights to any of these refunds? If not this is simply a Dina deMalkhuta question and we have to see what applicable local law says.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Ah! I missed those nuances that you mentioned in your 2nd comment!

Comment: I think that a major piece of resolving this is knowing who is ultimately responsible for returns. Sometimes when I buy an appliance from say, Macy's they say in their policy, that manufacturer defects go to the manufacturer - i.e. - they've relinquished their responsibility. So, the manufacturer has to issue the refund. If Macy's gives you an additional one, that's a mistake and I think it follows the rules in the link (extra change).

Comment: In your scenario, it sounds like the retailer may have done you a "favor". Need a bit more detail from you.

Comment: The second case (that you just added) seems to be different case entirely. I can argue that he knowingly let you keep it, so it makes it like a gift. Whereas in the first case you're dealing with two parties.